# Pass content from one @include into another @include in Laravel's Blade template

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Is it possible to pass content from one @include into another @include file in Laravel's Blade template?

I have the main content @include where most content is generated, but sometimes i would like to pass some content into Sidebar, not sure can that be done.

Below is the main template that pulls all includes together.
I would like to pass content from 'content' to '_sidebar', would that be possible?

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        @include('partials._top_nav')
        @include('partials._sidebar') 
    </nav>
    <!-- /Navigation -->
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
             @yield('content')
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you call the view pass the variable in the view 
like this:-
Controller code:-

```
$testing = "abcd";
return view('test', compact('testing')
```

Now $testing is available in the view and also the master layout so from the master wherever you are including the partials you can pass the variable like this

```
@include('view.name', ['variable_name' => $testing])
```

Now $testing is available in the partial as well..

hope this helps